# Android TextToSpeech setLanguage works on emulator but not on the phone

Tags: android

I am having a very annoying problem with Android TextToSpeech API. 
When I try to set up a language like this for example :

```
int result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.GERMANY);
```

The result is SUCCESS, but the TTS still uses default language, instead of the one I set up.

The weird thing is that on the emulator it works perfectly, the problem only occurs on my galaxy S.

Comment: I have the same problem. setLanguage() doesn't work. I must go to Android Settings and choose language there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The language isn't guaranteed to be available, the SDK reference says:

public int setLanguage (Locale loc)
Since: API Level 4

Sets the language for the TextToSpeech engine. The TextToSpeech engine will try to use the closest match to the specified language as represented by the Locale, but there is no guarantee that the exact same Locale will be used. **Use isLanguageAvailable(Locale) to check the level of support before choosing the language to use for the next utterances**.

So it looks like it may not always be possible to have you chosen language.

Comment: Well it's kinda weird cause the locales I try to set up are returned by the getAvailableLocales() method. In addition if I switch the phone to another language, this other language will be used. It seems wathever I do the phone language is used.

Answer (score 0):

in Galaxy we should change TextToSpeech Settings manually